# w/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_

Tags: tensorflow, installation

i installed it but pycharm and google corab always error
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4SQp.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMvYO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsQji.jpg)

how to fix it?

installed tensorflow but i couldn't fix the error

Comment: You installed it in your local computer, Colab does not run in your local computer, the code runs on Google's servers.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow's latest version `TF 2.11` supports only `python 3.10` as mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/). Please try again after downgrading the [python](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package_location) version from 3.11.

Please check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74556733/tensorflow-support-for-python3-11) for your reference.