# Tensorflow support for Python3.11

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.11

I have Python3.11.0 on a Windows10 PC.
Trying to install tensorflow using:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

gives error. Upon visiting the tensorflow site I realised that it supports only 3.7 - 3.10
Should I downgrade the python version or is any workaround available?

Comment: use pyenv - you can run multiple python versions

Comment: Follow/vote for the 3.11 support issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/58032

Answer (score 5):

[Tensorflow 2.12 has been released with python 3.11 support,](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.12.0) so you can now consolidate your python installations and package setups

Comment: Just wanted to add that one of the tensorflow dependencies (tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem) has specified that in its latest version works with Python >=3.11, but <3.12.

If you are using poetry for dependency management, ensure that your Python version is limited to the same in order to enable the installation.

Comment: 2.12 is not, and won't ever be available for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should downgrade python to < 3.11 until the wheels are updated to support python 3.11

Answer (score 3):

tensorflow currently supports from python 3.7 - 3.10 4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create a conda environment using python 3.10 to use tensorflow. Here's a link with instructions to follow : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos

Comment: An example in addition to the link would be useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33493297)

Answer (score 0):

python3.10 only works with tensorflow, don't use 3.11 or 3.12 python version, it doesn't support on Windows 11 64bit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).